# How to make any View conform to View, for use with ImageRenderer?

Tags: swiftui, protocols

I have this protocol

```
protocol Slide: View {
 ///
}

class MyClass {

   let slides: [any Slide]

}
```

I then want to use `ImageRenderer`  to make a screenshot of a given slide, since they are `View`, this should be possible.

But when send `ImageRenderer` a `Slide` from `slides`,

```
let aSlide = slides[0]
let screenshot = ImageRenderer(content: aSlide)
```

i get the error

```
Type any View cannot conform to View
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using generics:

```swift
class MyClass<Content> where Content: Slide {

    let slides: [Content]

}
```

I'm not sure how your classes all tie together and how an ImageRenderer is normally used, but I found that this at least compiles without errors:

```swift
struct MyView<Content>: View where Content: Slide {

    let slides: [Content]

    var body: some View {
        let aSlide = slides[0]
        let screenshot = ImageRenderer(content: aSlide)
        return screenshot.content
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case i have trouble defining the MyClass as a variable, var myClass: MyClass<Slide> // error: type Any Slide cannot conform to Slide

Comment: It would work if you had a specific type of Slide, var myClass: MyClass<MySlide>, otherwise you have to ripple the use of generics further.